# How to deploy react-native application from Intellij IDEA (Ultimate) to Microsoft Emulator?

Tags: android, react-native, intellij-idea, android-emulator, hyper-v

Android SDK emulator is not compatible with Hyper-V (which is required on Windows to run Docker). I have installed Microsoft Emulator instead as I do need Docker as well. When I start the emulator, and then run the project from Intellij, I end up with:

> :app:installDebug Skipping device 'emulator-5580' (emulator-5580):
>   Device is OFFLINE. :app:installDebug FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2 mins 2.478 secs
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.

How do I deploy react-native app from Intellij to Microsoft Emulator?